# Span and linear independence. Test review; not homework.

Tags: linear-algebra

The following is a question on my exam review.

> [image]

The answer (from the answer key) is C, but why?

**Here is my analysis:**

The set does not span $R^3$ because there is not a pivot in every row of the reduced matrix in echelon form (contradicts the first statement in answer C).

The set IS linearly independent.  Because, if I row-reduce the matrix A to:

```
Matrix A = [v1,v2]

   1 0     1 0
   0 1  ~  0 1
   0 2     0 0 (-2R2 + R3)
```

I get a pivot in every column, meaning that the vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent, right?

I can see that the set is not a basis for R^3 as ColA does not span R^3, but two out of three statements in answer C contradict my analysis.  **What am I doing wrong?**

**Answer key:**

> [image: answer key]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is right that the set doesn't span $\mathbb{R}^3$. Note how the choices say A) A B) D C) B D) C, meaning that if the correct answer is C, statement B is actually correct.

Comment: Ah!  I am getting tired.  Thanks. :)  I flagged this question for deletion.  I will accept your answer in 8 minutes if the question is still here.

Comment: You're welcome. Out of curiosity, what book are you studying from, and why would the authors make the choices so confusing?

Comment: We're using Linear Algebra, David C. Lay, 4th Edition, but these problems are from a PDF my prof. e-mailed us, and I don't know from what source they were generated.   And  I don't know, but it seems deliberately confusing, testing attention to detail for no reason at all! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have to do row-reduction to see  the vectors are linearly independent: it is perfectly clear  that any linear relation between the vectors has both coefficients eqaul to $0$.

They do not span $\mathbf R^3$ because any basis has $3$ vectors, not $2$.

Comment: So is it true that any basis of $R^n$ would have n vectors?

Comment: More precisely, the theorem that allows to define the dimension of a vector space is this: The  following numbers are equal, if they exist: $\;(i)$  the *maximum* number of a system of linearly independent vectors; $\;(ii)$ the *minimal* number of elements in a system of vectors spanning $\mathbf R^n$. Furthermore, this is true for any vector space over any field.

Comment: Hmm, okay, thanks!